# Using Ajax to render a partial in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

this post is the last chance to work out why ajax call doesn't work in my project. Hope you guys will give me a hand.

What I solely want is to render a partial of "orders" to my administration page by clicking on "link_to" button.

This is what I have in controller called "masters":

```
class MastersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_master, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_master,   only: [:edit, :update]


  def administration
  @orders = Order.all       
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
    format.js
    end
  end
```

My view called "administration.html.erb":

```
<% provide(:title, "Administration") %>
<h1>Manage your site</h1>


<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><%= link_to "Masters", masters_path %></li>
  <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Orders", orders_path, action:remote => true %></li>
  <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Settings", edit_master_path(current_master) %></li>
  <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Services", manage_path %></li>
  <li style="float:right;" role="presentation"><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
</ul>


<div class="activity">

</div>
```

My js format of the view called "administration.js.erb":

```
var orders_inject = $("<%= escape_javascript(render (:partial => 'orders')) %>");
$('.activity').html(orders_inject); 

and my partial itself called "orders":

<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Field</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Mobile number</th>
      <th>Photo</th>
      <th>Master</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr class="active">
        <td><%= order.name %></td>
        <td><%= order.field %></td>
        <td><%= order.description %></td>
        <td><%= order.address %></td>
        <td><%= order.datetime %></td>
        <td><%= order.mobile_number %></td>
        <td><%= order.photo %></td>   
        <td><%= order.master_id %></td> 
        <td><%= link_to 'Add master', edit_order_path(order), class: 'btn btn-info btn-sm' %></td>   
        <td><%= link_to 'Delete order', order, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So please, help me to figure out as I've been reading various related post almost for a week and still no solution for this bug. Really appreciate any comment and advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.activity').html("<%= j raw render 'orders' %>")
```

Where 'orders' is located in app/views/masters/orders.html.erb

Comment: You mean I gotta place this code inside orders.html.erb?

Comment: Could you please clarify it for me?

Comment: replace the line "$('.activity').html(orders_inject);" with the solution above

Comment: Although it wasn't the case, thank you a lot for your effort.